# Regarding one to one mapping in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I am a new bie to the world of hibernate could you please advise , I was going through one to one relationship in Hibernate,
As per my analysis , one to one hibernate relationships can be established by three ways..

```
1)Through Join concept
2)Same primary key in both the tables
3)Primary key and foriegn key relationship in both the tables
```

**Please advise , the above three ways to achieve the one to one mapping is correct or I am missing something then please advise, and also please advise that the below hbm mapping files that I am using are correct one.if not then please advise**.

1) Through Join concept :-
One way to achieve to one to one relationship is by joining concept ,  following xml is being used for that

```
<hibernate-mapping>

<class name="mypack.Person" table="person21">
<id name="personId" type="int">
<generator class="increment">
</generator>
</id>
<property name="name"/>

<join table="personAddress">
<key column="personId"/>
<many-to-one name="address" class="mypack.Address" column="addressId" unique="true" cascade="all"/>
</join>
</class>

<class name="mypack.Address" table="address21">
<id name="id" column="addressId" type="int">
<generator class="increment"/>
</id>
<property name="city"/>
<property name="state"/>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

2) Same primary key in both the tables  :-

Using same primary key in  both the tables , following hbm is being used for that

```
 <class name="mypack.Address" table="address31">
<id name="id" column="addressId" type="int">
<generator class="increment"/>
</id>
<property name="city"/>
<property name="state"/>
</class>

<class name="mypack.Person" table="person31">
<id name="personId" type="int">
<generator class="foreign">
<param name="property">address</param>
</generator>
</id>
<property name="name"/>
<one-to-one name="address" class="mypack.Address"/>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

3)Primary key and foriegn key relationship in both the tables  :-

Primary key in one table and  foriegn key in another table. below is the hbm for this

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="mypack.Person">
<id name="personId" type="int">
<generator class="increment"/>
</id>
<property name="name"/>

<many-to-one name="address" class="mypack.Address" column="addressId" unique="true" cascade="all"/>
</class>


<class name="mypack.Address">
<id name="id" column="addressId" type="int">
<generator class="increment"/>
</id>
<property name="city"/>
<property name="state"/>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

folks please advise.

Comment: Have you considered using annotations instead of xml mapping? It's probably easier if you're new to this and there are plenty of good tutorials to get started.

Comment: @MagnusTengdahl Thanks,Yeah I have to choose XML , please advise is this hbm xml mappings are correct or do they require any modification

Comment: I don't work with xml mapping and hibernate, I have a strong preference to use annotations. But you are trying to perform a simple one-to-one relationship, just follow a tutorial such as: http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-one-to-one-1.html

Answer (score 0):

I really think that join table is overkill here for a one-to-one mapping. For the other 2 solutions, please take a look at the following Hibernate documentation, everything is explained : http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-onetoone.

For your second mapping (primary key association), both entities need to define a one-to-one mapping and one side of the relation also needs to specify the attribute `constrained="true"`.

This is how I would write your second mapping :

```
<class name="mypack.Person" table="PERSONS">
    <id name="id" type="int" column="PERSON_ID">
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <property name="name" type="string" column="NAME"/>
    <one-to-one name="address" class="mypack.Address" cascade="all"/>
</class>

<class name="mypack.Address" table="ADDRESSES">
    <id name="id" type="int" column="ADDRESS_ID">
        <generator class="foreign">
            <param name="property">address</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
    <property name="city" type="string" column="CITY"/>
    <property name="state" type="string" column="STATE"/>
    <one-to-one name="person" class="mypack.Person" constrained="true"/>
</class>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, regarding second mapping , please let me know there is a url http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example/  ..it has shown the way that you want to communicate

Comment: Thanks a lot could you also please advise for third mapping also.

Comment: also please advise one to one tab is there in both the class tag of two tables, please advise why it is there in both the class tags , in order to maintain the bi directional relationship..? please advise